# Different syntaxes for creating Actors in Akka

Tags: scala, akka

I have seen quite a few syntaxes for creating an Actor:

```
  system.actorOf(Props(new A(a, b)), "name")
  system.actorOf(Props(classOf[A], a, b), "name")
  system.actorOf(Props[A], "name")
  system.actorOf(A(a).props(), "name")
```

When should one use each of these?

If there are more, additions are welcome.

Comment: Generally put `def props(a: Int, b: Int) = Props(new A(a, b))` in companion object of `A` and use `system.actorOf(A.props(1, 2))`. For more, see http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.1/scala/actors.html#Recommended_Practices

Answer (score 1):

I prefer construction with companion object like:

```scala
    object MyActor {
      def props(): Props = Props[ClientActor]
    }

    class MyActor extends Actor {
     def receive: Receive = {
        ...
     }
    }
```

If you need some parameters put to the actor you can use:

```scala
object MyActorHandler {
  def props(parameter: String, address: SocketAddress): Props =
    Props(classOf[ClientActorHandler], parameter, address)
}

class MyActorHandler(parameter: String, address: SocketAddress)
    extends Actor {

        def receive: Receive = {
            ...
         }
}
```

When you add more parameter to the Actor constructor you have all in one place.

Second suggestion: create actor by `context.actorOf()` from supervisor. Create actor hierarchy.For more details see [Supervision and Monitoring](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.2/general/supervision.html)

Comment: Also `MyActor.props(..)` plays nicely with DI frameworks.